# Domain model entities vs data entities, one or both in software architecture

Tags: c#, java, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

```
**Update 2**
```

I have a project with a typical 3 layer structure(UI/Domain/Data layer). What is the pros and cons to have both domain model entities in domain layer and data entities layer.

The possibility of changing to different database is slim. What is the pros and cons of having  only data entities in data layer as domain model entities? What is the difference if ORM is used (Is it good practice to have both entities when ORM (NHibernate) is used)?

Please fire your ideas, or links, articles, books.

**Update 3**

In what circumstances we should use both domain entity and data entity?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is about DDD. In a typical DDD scenario, Domain entities are 'hydrated' by Data layer (which is often thin because it uses ORM). In order to hydrate Domain entities, Data layer has to have intimate knowledge of the domain. If you use ORM than you most likely not need separate 'data entities', ORM knows how to reconstitute your Domain objects. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank! Is it good practice to have both entities when ORM is used

Comment: You don't need 'data entities' at all if you use good ORM, it does the mapping for you. This is the whole purpose of ORM.

Comment: So is the entity in data layer being both domain model entities and data entities?

Comment: @Pingpong normal practice is using domain entities both in domain layer and thin data access layer. But also keep in mind that sending domain entities to UI is not very good practice. Usually set of dto objects used to provide data for UI.

Comment: In what circumstances we should use both domain entity and data entity?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you mean by 'data entity' but I would guess that this is just a sort of DTO that is used by custom data access to reconstitute actual domain objects. Maybe you need them if you don't have ORM or you hand rolling your own...

Answer (score 1):

Using data entities with domain entities is a tricky thing to do and adds another not necessary layer of abstraction without adding any value.

You should either use full-featured domain model mapped via ORM or 'anaemic' data model (also mapped via ORM). Which one depends on your background, requirements and personal preferences.

In case of data model, you probably map directly tables to entities (one-to-one) without any complex stuff like inheritance hierarchy mapping. That's fine. The tricky thing is mapping 1:n relationships. With data model they tend to work well if you don't represent the 'many' side in object model. Why? Because both relation ends will easily be out of sync if you don't add custom code to handle these cases.

In case of domain model, you probably use repositories to fetch your aggregate roots.

There is exception to what I've written. It is legitimate to use both data entities and domain entities in CQRS architecture.

Answer (score 1):

You use data entities if your data schema does not map exactly onto your domain entities. For example, consider a telephone number. In your domain entity, it may be one single property whereas in the database it may consist of an area code field and a telephone number field.

Contrary to what some answers suggest, the data access layer DOES NOT hydrate your domain entities and DOES NOT have intimate knowledge of them. Instead, your domain layer asks your data access layer for data needed to reconstruct instances.

Answer (score 0):

The domain model should exist in as many places as possible to maximize code reuse and understanding.  The exception to this would when using the domain model is prohibitively expensive, in either time, memory or transportation costs.

Let's say the you have have a supplier for parts.  This supplier supplies thousands of parts to you, so the one-to-many in this case might be huge, especially considering the web of classes each part might bring along.  However, you need a list of parts from a specific supplier for a specific widget.  In this case, you create a value object with the just the data you need.

This value object can be a copy of the supplier object, with only the parts you need, or it can be a completely new class representing only the data you need.

The typical use case for this might be displaying the data on a web page, and your transferring the data via json.

Comment: From you explanation, am I right that domain model can exist in all 3 layers without data entities at all in some cases, e.g. Dmitry's kind explanation?

Comment: Yes.  Absolutely.  It's a question of performance vs ease of maintenance.  It's easier to write and maintain code that directly interacts with a domain model.